# Do rivers cause eco-damage in Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri?

Tags: alpha-centauri

Looking at [a StrategyWiki page](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Alpha_Centauri/Terraforming), I see that condensers, which cause rain, cause eco-damage.

I can only presume that is because Planet prefers to be dry, or that rain causes plants which destroy fungus.

Using that logic, I should be afraid to "drill to aquifer" and create a new river. However, the same page does not mention any eco-damage.

Can anyone cite a reference as to whether "drill to aquifer" causes eco-damage or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the internet has non-authoritative (opinion) answers to your question [[see 'terraforming hints', here](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Alpha_Centauri/Winning_tips#Terraforming_hints)], the [game user manual](https://www.spacegamejunkie.com/docs/Alpha_Centauri_-_Manual_-_PC.pdf) (starting at the 'ecological risks' section [on page 54]) reads as follows (my comments are in the [] brackets):

> '...each **technological** enhancement constructed on any square in a
>   base's production radius increases that base's ecological disruption.
>   In general, the more complex an enhancement (i.e. the longer it takes
>   to complete), the greater the damage it causes. Also, the higher a
>   base's mineral production, the greater the chance of ecological
>   disaster.'
>
> 'Your ecological damage ranking, as shown on your base screen [under
>   the label 'eco damage'] gives a percentage chance on each turn that
>   Planet will react to your disruptions in the form of uncontrolled
>   fungus blooms that wipe out all existing enhancements in a given
>   square, The new fungus also often spawns native life forms.'
>
> 'Ecological damage can be minimized (or even eliminated entirely)
>   through social engineering ['green' is especially good for this] and
>   secret projects (such as the Pholus Mutagen).'

So the although the user manual seems to imply that any change you make to a square [including drill to aquifer] will cause some ecological disruption, this is not always true. I have found that while building farms, mines, roads, and especially boreholes increases eco disruption, building forest or fungus in squares [non-technological terraforming] tends to decrease eco disruption and some terraforming, like 'drill to aquifer', or raise/lower/flatten terrain are more or less neutral to eco disruption.

In general, if you plant sufficient forest and fungus squares and don't have too high a mineral production in any given city, eco disruption is easily avoided, even if you do a lot of terraforming.

Comment: Thanks. It took 18 months to get an answer (how did you even find the question? ;-) but it's a good and convincing answer and will be sure to help others. \to be honest, I have never planted fungus, so will ask a new question as why I might want to. Please see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351201/why-would-i-want-to-plant-fungus-in-smac-sid-maiers-alpha-centauri)

Comment: @ Mawg: I haven't been active on this site over the past several years, but tend to look for questions on games I like to play like SMAC. I made a stab at answering your new question as well.

Comment: Thanks. [This page](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Sid_Meier%27s_Alpha_Centauri/Winning_tips#Terraforming_hints) says "`River is a pure bonus. No ecological damage too! Drill as much rivers as you can`"